# Why are the names Santiago/James said to be derived from the Latin Iacomus when they both sound so differnent?

Tags: latín

This is a very broad question and could be asked of many names/words in European languages which are all said to be derived from the same Latin word.

How is it the Spanish/English spelling/sound can be so different while both being derived from the same Latin word? I know there's no J in Spanish, but Santiago and James share zero similarities? What am I missing? Please forgive my naivety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is that the name **Santiago** is composed by two particles: **Sant Iago** (Saint + James).

In [his Spanish entry in the wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santiago_el_Mayor#Onom%C3%A1stica) you can find a short explanation of the evolution of the name from the original **Jacob**:

> Su nombre en hebreo es Jacob (יעקב), pero con el tiempo se ha ido deformando en Jacobo, Iago, Yago, San Iago, San Yago, Santiago, Tiago o Thiago, Diego, Jaime, James, Jim, Jimmy, Jackes, Jacques. Decir San Santiago es un error.

How Jacob evolved to **James** is beyond the scope of this site but according to [this other wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_(name)) English takes it from Old French.